# Maven Cobertura plugin not generating coverage.xml

Tags: maven-plugin, maven-3, hudson-plugins, cobertura

I am trying to generate a coverage.xml so that I can reference it in Cobertura plugin of Hudson, but the file is not being created.

I've added the following to my POM

```
 <reporting>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
               <formats>
                   <format>html</format>
                   <format>xml</format>
               </formats>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</reporting>
```

After running mvn cobertura:cobertura, the HTML site is generated as expected at **\target\site\cobertura, but coverage.xml is nowhere to be found.   What am I missing/misunderstanding?

I am running Maven 3.0.3

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm still quite a novice with the connections between Maven Plugins and Hudson and it's plugins - so this isn't an intelligent answer by any means, but help on Google is very few and far between for this issue - so hopefully it helps someone in the future.

After spending a few more hours of tinkering with settings, I've found that the coverage.xml simply doesn't seem to be built locally.

This is the combination that got it working:

1. I had changed my version to 2.2 in my POM (I was getting resource
   not found errors from Apache with 2.5.1)
2. Added cobertura:cobertura in my Hudson goal
3. Set the Cobertura coverage pattern to the
   recommended **/target/site/cobertura/coverage.xml

Answer (score 30):

Add below lines to your application Goals:(configure section of the application in jenkins)

```
cobertura:cobertura -Dcobertura.report.format=xml
```

pom.xml changes:

```
<reporting>
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
        <configuration>
            <formats>
                <format>html</format>
                <format>xml</format>
            </formats>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

Comment: Note that even though the pom configuration specifies both `html` and `xml`, the command line argument overrides that, instructing the plugin to generate only `xml`.

Comment: Thanks for the -D argument

Answer (score 27):

I put the plugin in the build section and it works:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <formats>
                    <format>html</format>
                    <format>xml</format>
                </formats>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

The reporting section and its differences to the plugin section are described [here](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Reporting). I don't know if this is a maven [3.0.4] or cobertura-plugin issue.

Answer (score 3):

My objective was to get Cobertura to run duing `mvn test` with no additional command line parameters. Here's the magic XML that did the trick for me, with both the HTML and XML being generated in `/target/site/cobertura`.

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.7</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>cobertura</id>
                    <phase>test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>cobertura</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <formats>
                            <format>xml</format>
                            <format>html</format>
                        </formats>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue but it's resolved right now:
Just add `-Dcobertura.report.format=xml` after your maven command. It should work

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue using 2.6 of the plugin.

I found that when I specify both types, I only got html.

```
           <formats>
               <format>html</format>
               <format>xml</format>
           </formats>
```

But when I specify only xml, I get an xml report.

```
           <formats>
               <format>xml</format>
           </formats>
```

This is probably a bug in the plugin.

Another user suggested creating two executions. I tried that with no success (meaning I got html, but not xml).

Answer (score 0):

Update your POM file as

```
<build>
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.7</version>
        <configuration>
            <formats>
                <format>html</format>
                <format>xml</format>
            </formats>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

This worked out for me:  Probable reason it contanis the latest version of cobertura-maven-plugin (2.7)

Answer (score 0):

The are two ways to integrate Cobertura into Maven.

1. Put Cobertura into the *build* section of the pom file, then you have to execute **mvn clean cobertura:cobertura** to generate the reports. If you have XML and HTML configured, then you get both reports.
2. Put Cobertura into the *reporting* section of the pom file, then you have to execute **mvn clean site** to generate the reports. If you have XML and HTML configured, then you get both reports. Additionally you get a generated site (open target/site/index.html) with all reports integrated e.g. Coberture, Checkstyle, ...