# Code Coverage: Cobertura and SonarQube 5.3 Maven Integration

Tags: maven-3, code-coverage, cobertura, sonarqube5.3, maven-cobertura-plugin

We are migrating all the project from ANT to MAVEN as part of Continuous Integration. We are using JaCoCo for new project to measure the code coverage and integrated successfully with SonarQube.

We have few existing ANT project which is using Cobertura. While migrating this to Maven I am getting the below exception

**Exception**

```
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.0.2:sonar (default-cli) on project CoberturaMaven: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxIOException: Invalid UTF-8 start byte 0xac (at char #1, byte #-1)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:217)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxIOException: Invalid UTF-8 start byte 0xac (at char #1, byte #-1)
at org.sonarsource.scanner.maven.bootstrap.ExceptionHandling.handle(ExceptionHandling.java:36)
at org.sonarsource.scanner.maven.bootstrap.ScannerBootstrapper.execute(ScannerBootstrapper.java:81)
at org.sonarsource.scanner.maven.SonarQubeMojo.execute(SonarQubeMojo.java:112)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
... 19 more
Caused by: org.sonar.api.utils.XmlParserException: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxIOException: Invalid UTF-8 start byte 0xac (at char #1, byte #-1)
at org.sonar.plugins.cobertura.CoberturaReportParser.parse(CoberturaReportParser.java:71)
at org.sonar.plugins.cobertura.CoberturaReportParser.parseReport(CoberturaReportParser.java:57)
at org.sonar.plugins.cobertura.CoberturaSensor.parseReport(CoberturaSensor.java:69)
at org.sonar.plugins.cobertura.CoberturaSensor.analyse(CoberturaSensor.java:64)
at org.sonar.batch.phases.SensorsExecutor.executeSensor(SensorsExecutor.java:58)
at org.sonar.batch.phases.SensorsExecutor.execute(SensorsExecutor.java:50)
at org.sonar.batch.phases.PhaseExecutor.execute(PhaseExecutor.java:98)
at org.sonar.batch.scan.ModuleScanContainer.doAfterStart(ModuleScanContainer.java:185)
at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:132)
at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:117)
at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scan(ProjectScanContainer.java:243)
at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:238)
at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.doAfterStart(ProjectScanContainer.java:228)
at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:132)
at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:117)
at org.sonar.batch.task.ScanTask.execute(ScanTask.java:55)
at org.sonar.batch.task.TaskContainer.doAfterStart(TaskContainer.java:86)
at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:132)
at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:117)
at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.GlobalContainer.executeTask(GlobalContainer.java:122)
at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.executeTask(Batch.java:119)
at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.batch.BatchIsolatedLauncher.execute(BatchIsolatedLauncher.java:62)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherProxy.invoke(IsolatedLauncherProxy.java:60)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy15.execute(Unknown Source)
at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.doExecute(EmbeddedScanner.java:240)
at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.runAnalysis(EmbeddedScanner.java:151)
at org.sonarsource.scanner.maven.bootstrap.ScannerBootstrapper.execute(ScannerBootstrapper.java:78)
... 22 more
Caused by: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxIOException: Invalid UTF-8 start byte 0xac (at char #1, byte #-1)
at com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.constructFromIOE(StreamScanner.java:633)
at com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.loadMore(StreamScanner.java:1007)
at com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.getNext(StreamScanner.java:762)
at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.nextFromProlog(BasicStreamReader.java:2002)
at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.next(BasicStreamReader.java:1131)
at org.codehaus.staxmate.in.SMHierarchicCursor.getNext(SMHierarchicCursor.java:71)
at org.codehaus.staxmate.in.SMInputCursor.advance(SMInputCursor.java:1631)
at org.sonar.plugins.cobertura.CoberturaReportParser$1.stream(CoberturaReportParser.java:65)
at org.sonar.api.utils.StaxParser.parse(StaxParser.java:113)
at org.sonar.api.utils.StaxParser.parse(StaxParser.java:93)
at org.sonar.api.utils.StaxParser.parse(StaxParser.java:83)
at org.sonar.plugins.cobertura.CoberturaReportParser.parse(CoberturaReportParser.java:69)
... 52 more
Caused by: java.io.CharConversionException: Invalid UTF-8 start byte 0xac (at char #1, byte #-1)
at com.ctc.wstx.io.UTF8Reader.reportInvalidInitial(UTF8Reader.java:303)
at com.ctc.wstx.io.UTF8Reader.read(UTF8Reader.java:189)
at com.ctc.wstx.io.ReaderSource.readInto(ReaderSource.java:86)
at com.ctc.wstx.io.BranchingReaderSource.readInto(BranchingReaderSource.java:56)
at com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.loadMore(StreamScanner.java:1001)
... 62 more
```

**pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.test</groupId>
<artifactId>CoberturaMaven</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>
<name>CoberturaMaven</name>
<description>This is maven version of cobertura sonarqube integration</description>

<properties>
    <!-- JAVA Version -->
    <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>

    <!-- Cobertura SonarQube Setup -->
    <sonar.core.codeCoveragePlugin>cobertura</sonar.core.codeCoveragePlugin>
    <sonar.java.coveragePlugin>cobertura</sonar.java.coveragePlugin>
    <sonar.junit.reportsPath>${project.basedir}/target/surefire-reports</sonar.junit.reportsPath>
    <sonar.surefire.reportsPath>${project.basedir}/target/surefire-reports</sonar.surefire.reportsPath>
    <sonar.cobertura.reportPath>${project.basedir}/target/cobertura/cobertura.ser</sonar.cobertura.reportPath>

    <!-- SONAR -->
    <sonar.login>changeIt</sonar.login>
    <sonar.password>changeIt</sonar.password>
    <sonar.projectKey>cobertura-maven</sonar.projectKey>
    <sonar.projectName>CoberturaMaven</sonar.projectName>
    <sonar.projectVersion>27Jun2016</sonar.projectVersion>
    <sonar.sources>src/main/java</sonar.sources>
    <sonar.java.binaries>target/classes</sonar.java.binaries>
    <sonar.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</sonar.sourceEncoding>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <sonar.language>java</sonar.language>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <!-- Test -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.7</version>
            <configuration>
                <instrumentation>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*.class</include>
                    </includes>
                </instrumentation>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>clean</id>
                    <phase>pre-site</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>clean</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>instrument</id>
                    <phase>site</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>instrument</goal>
                        <goal>cobertura</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        <!-- SonarQube Plugin -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.sonarsource.scanner.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
</build>

<reporting>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <!-- use mvn cobertura:cobertura to generate cobertura reports -->
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.7</version>
            <configuration>
                <formats>
                    <format>html</format>
                    <format>xml</format>
                </formats>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</reporting>

</project>
```

Expert, am I missing anything here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I did not get any answer yet from anyone. But I solved this on my own as described in the

[sonar importing cobertura.ser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11049123/sonar-importing-cobertura-ser-coverage-reports-to-sonar-server-using-mvn-sonars).

The issue is sonar-maven-plugin was expecting coverage.xml file but I was pointing to cobertura.ser.

I changed it to

```
<sonar.cobertura.reportPath>${project.basedir}/target/site/cobertura/coverage.xml</sonar.cobertura.reportPath>
```

Secondly, I found one issue with cobertura-maven-plugin (version: 2.7) it is not generating coverage.xml file even though in report format I have specified xml. This issues is already pointed in the below stackoverflow link

[Maven Cobertura plugin not generating coverage.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9398662/maven-cobertura-plugin-not-generating-coverage-xml)

```
<plugin>
    <!-- use mvn cobertura:cobertura to generate cobertura reports -->
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.7</version>
    <configuration>
        <formats>
            <format>xml</format>
        </formats>
</plugin>
```

I have to pass **-Dcobertura.report.format=xml** this property to generate the coverage.xml

The final plugin configuration looks like this

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.7</version>
            <configuration>
                <instrumentation>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*.class</include>
                    </includes>
                </instrumentation>
                <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>clean</id>
                    <phase>pre-site</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>clean</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>instrument</id>
                    <phase>site</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>instrument</goal>
                        <goal>cobertura</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        <!-- SonarQube Plugin -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.sonarsource.scanner.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
</build>

<reporting>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <!-- use mvn cobertura:cobertura to generate cobertura reports -->
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.7</version>
            <configuration>
                <formats>
                    <format>xml</format>
                </formats>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</reporting>
```

And I am using the below command to execute the code coverage and publishing to SonarQube

**clean install cobertura:cobertura sonar:sonar -Dcobertura.report.format=xml**

Comment: The sonar-examples repo : https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-examples/tree/master/projects/languages/java/code-coverage/ut/ut-maven-cobertura has been fixed accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Hi with this below code i am able to generate both xml as well as html files

```
<build>
    <plugins>
         <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.7</version>
                <configuration>
                    <instrumentation>
                        <includes>
                            <include>**/*.class</include>
                        </includes>
                    </instrumentation>
                    <encoding>Cp1252</encoding>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>clean</id>
                        <phase>pre-site</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>clean</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>instrument</id>
                        <phase>site</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>instrument</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <encoding>Cp1252</encoding>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>cobertura</id>
                        <phase>test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>cobertura</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <formats>
                                <format>xml</format>
                                <format>html</format>
                            </formats>
                            <encoding>Cp1252</encoding>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <!-- SonarQube Plugin -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.sonarsource.scanner.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.2</version>
            </plugin>
       </plugins>
</build>
<reporting>
        <plugins>
            <!-- Normally, we take off the dependency report, saves time. -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.7</version>
                <configuration>
                    <dependencyLocationsEnabled>false</dependencyLocationsEnabled>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </reporting>
```